# Batch to open files with the same extension in sub-folders in Windows

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I need to open a large number of files that have the same extension in one folder; these files are also in sub-folders inside this one folder.

How do I open all of them using CMD. The files are self-executable since they're `.bat` files and each executes specific commands when I double click them manually.

Comment: Julia -- I added an answer for you so give it a shot when you get a chance and let me know if you find it of any usefulness for your need. You can use the below as a batch script or you can make a small change to the `%%A` and `%%~A` to make those use only one percent sign so.... `%A` and `%~A` and all should work from command line manually running that logic. Reply back when you get a chance and let me know.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT I tried your script it didn't do anything. Actually, I didn't get an error message, I suppose something happened, does this script create a batch file somewhere on my computer that I can execute later? When I used single % instead of the double % only the first .bat file was executed. By the way, I need to run all of the batch files at once (parallel). Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Here is what I put  C:\Users\Rania\AppData\Roaming\Ladybug  my Ladybug folder has sub-folders that have the .bat files. and I ran the command from the Roaming folder.

Comment: I tried to run script 1,2, and 3 as an administrator. I got the same results as the initial results I got from running script 1 using both  "%" and "%%". In fact, running script three I got this error "%%A was unexpected this time"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43582/discussion-between-pimp-juice-it-and-julia-arch).

Comment: If you can click on the chat link and let's move to a chat where you can easily send me screen shots as well so I'm just throwing ideas out there now. We can try using the START command in one of the scripts but I'd like to see what you see from the command prompt when you execute one of these batch scripts as in a screen shot or something... Open up a command prompt as administrator and then type in the full path to the batch script from my answer so it runs in that window and everything is visible so it doesn't just disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the below batch script a shot which uses a [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop and a [CALL](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) to execute each `.bat` file explicitly (with a [CALL](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html)) starting from the RootDir location and traverse recursively from there to find and execute all `.bat` files in other subfolders beneath it.

Be sure to change the `SET RootDir=C:\Folder` variable value to the folder path you need to find the `.bat` files starting from it and looking through all subfolders within it which contain other `.bat` files you need to execute (i.e. `SET RootDir=C:\OtherFolder`).

**Batch Script 1**

```
@ECHO ON 
SET RootDir=C:\Folder

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('DIR /S /B "%RootDir%\*.bat"') DO CALL "%%~A"
GOTO EOF
```

**Batch Script 2**

```
@ECHO ON 
SET RootDir=C:\Folder

CD /D "%RootDir%"
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('DIR /S /B "*.bat"') DO CALL "%%~A"
GOTO EOF
```

**Batch Script 3**

```
@ECHO ON 
SET RootDir=C:\Folder

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('DIR /S /B "%RootDir%\*.bat"') DO CMD /C "%%~A"
GOTO EOF
```

**Batch Script 4**

```
@ECHO ON 
SET RootDir=C:\Folder

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('DIR /S /B "%RootDir%\*.bat"') DO START "" "%%~A"
GOTO EOF
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**FOR /F**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [**CALL**](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html)
- [**DIR**](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [**START**](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)